# How to query Firebase Realtime Database using on() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to query a Firebase Realtime Database to retrieve a specific user based on their email using JavaScript. I want to use the equalTo and orderByChild methods together in my query, but I'm encountering issues. Here's the code snippet I have:

```
const usersRef = ref(database, 'users');
const userEmail = "testemail123@gmail.com";

const query = query(usersRef, orderByChild('email'), equalTo(userEmail));

emailQuery.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          // The user with the email address `userEmail` was found.
          const user = snapshot.val();
          console.log(user)
        } else {
          // The user with the email address `userEmail` was not found.
        }
      });
```

However, when I run this code, I get an error indicating that emailQuery.on is not defined. It seems that I cannot use on() directly within the query function.

> Sign-in error: emailQuery.on is not a function

How can I define "on()"? How can I modify my code to achieve my desired functionality?

I already tried other functions like once or forEach but they seem to provide the same error.

I've also tried this code:

```
      const usersRef = ref(database, 'users');
      console.log(usersRef);

      usersRef.orderByChild('email').equalTo(userEmail)
      .once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        const userObject = snapshot.val();
        console.log(userObject);
      })
```

but it just provides me this error:

> Sign-in error: usersRef.orderByChild is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing SDK versions/syntaxes.

This line uses the modular syntax introduced in SDK version 9:

```
const query = query(usersRef, orderByChild('email'), equalTo(userEmail));
```

But in this line you then try to use the namespaced API calls that have always existed:

```
emailQuery.on('value', (snapshot) => {
```

While both syntaxes continue to be supported, you can't use mix and match them at will. In a single file you will have to use one or the other.

The equivalent of `ref.on(...)` in the modular syntax, is the global `onValue` function as shown in the Firebase documentation on [listening for value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web-modular-api_2).

Based on that, you'd need:

```
onValue(emailQuery, (snapshot) => {
  ...
});
```